# How to reset iPhone 4S when home button does not work

Tags: iphone

How do I reset my phone if the home button doesn't work? I try'd the assisted touch but it still won't let it reset.

Comment: If you can open assisted touch I'm assuming the iPhones is not frozen - why reset it? Might as well just reboot it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: @KevinGrabher A reset causes some tasks to occur that do not occur during a normal power down/power up cycle (such as permanently deleting data caches for removed apps).